# JSON parse returns {Object, Object}

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am parsing the following JSON and it is supposed to return Message[] via a promise.  It is the same code used in the Heroes sample project in HTTP documentation

```
{
 "data": [
          {"id":"1","commid":"0","subject":"test1subject","body":"test1 body"},  
          {"id":"2","commid":"1","subject":"lkjhlkjh","body":"nbvjhg"}
 ]
}
```

It is instead returning data array with objects.  How can I get this to work like they did in example.  It needs to return a Message[]

```
return this.http.get('messages.json')
                .toPromise()
                .then(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);

private extractData(res: Response) {
   let body = res.json();
   console.log(body);
   return body.data || { };
}
```

Here is the code in my component

```
export class Message {
   id: number;
   commid: number; // community id that this msg belongs to
   subject: string;
   body: string;
}
   msgs:  Message[];
   this.msgService.getMessages().then(messages => {
       this.msgs = messages;
   });
```

Here is the angular doc sample:
http://plnkr.co/edit/KZGeyULqrcuZDSeg0CkF?p=preview

Comment: Are you asking about what is printed by the console.log() statement, or about what is returned in the promise? What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: Looking at the angular2 doc example, the json parse returns Hero[] via a promise, I want the same behavior.  I am using the same code.

Comment: Your promise does return an array containing two objects, and these objects contain an id, commid, etc., just as there is in the json. If you need to see what is indide these objects, use your debugger, or use `console.log(JSON.stringify(body.data))`. It's still unclear what you really expect, since you're not showing what Message is, nor showing any code using the returned promise.

Comment: I am also using the same JSON format as in the sample

Comment: I am using ngFor to iterate through the resulting array, just like in the sample

Comment: you aren't showing the entire method you are using; instead you are just showing a random return and saying it isn't returning what you expect.  You suggest that you expect a `Message[]`, and you are indeed returning an array;  if TypeScript isn't agreeing that this array is the same type as you expect, you need to provide more information, like the full signature of the function and the declaration of `Message`.

Comment: How do you convert string id in JSON to a number in angular class?

Comment: I think I got it working thanks

Comment: @Greg L. How did you get it working? I am experiencing the same issue. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following PHP to return what I wanted:

```
$item_type = "data";
$rows = array('data' => array());
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$rows['data'][] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```